# Incorrect cut for chat reply in global inbox

Tags: bug, chat, global-inbox

I have a chat reply that I see in global inbox like:

> [image: inbox]

You can see transcript for this message [here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/35046060#35046060).

> @alexolut Скорее всего потому, что под словами "кнопка «проголосовать»" вы имеете в виду что-то другое))

Seems double quote is wrongly split.

Comment: Ultimately, a large part of this is pragmatism - when we're trying to truncate text, we don't *usually* want to have to run a full html named entity search (plus general hex form). I'll have a think to see if we can do something that isn't going to hurt massively in terms of complexity and/or performance.